# What does $\cup*$ mean?

Tags: probability, notation

Today in a probability lecture our professor wrote $A \cup^* A^\complement = \Omega$, what is the meaning of the $*$ before $\cup$?

Comment: it means disjoint union. So union, but also the sets you're union-ing are disjoint or mutually exclusive

Comment: Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union